# RSA encryption given n, e and c

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

This is a previous exam paper question, as follows:

> Alice has a private key (d = 47, n = 1147) and a public key (e = 23, n = 1147). Bob wishes to send the message M = 3 to Alice. Perform the calculation Bob would do to encrypt this message for Alice.

How to encrypt using RSA?

$$
D = M^e \pmod n =
3^{23} \pmod {1147}
$$

By performing a direct calculation (or some RSA online calculator) as above:

$$
D = M^e \pmod{n} =
3^{23} \pmod {1147} = 724
$$

How to decrypt using RSA?

$$
M = D^d \pmod{1147} = 724^{47}\pmod {1147} = 3
$$

Unfortunately, when using efficient modular exponentiation or squaring method, I get a different result.

> 23 in binary is `10111` or `16 + 4 + 2 + 1`

Modular exponentiation for 23:

1. $ 23^1 \pmod{1147} = 23 $
2. $ 23^2 \pmod{1147} = 529 $
3. $ 23^4 \pmod{1147}= 529^2 \pmod{1147} = 1120 $
4. $ 23^8 \pmod{1147}= 1120^2 \pmod{1147} = 729 $
5. $ 23^{16} \pmod{1147}= 729^2 \pmod{1147} = 380 $

We then compute:

$$ 
3^{23}(mod 1147) = (380 * 1120 * 529 * 23)
$$

As follows:

1. $ 380 \cdot 1120 \pmod {1147} = 63 $
2. $ 63 \cdot 529 \pmod {1147} = 64 $
3. $ 64 \cdot 23 \pmod {1147} = 325 $

Then our encrypted message equals:

$$
 D = M^e \pmod {n} =
3^{23} \pmod {1147} = 325 
$$

Which is incorrect:

$$ 325 \neq 724 $$

When using the inverse process for decryption, it also gives me the wrong result, i.e. not the original message.

Is there any other way to do this that I am not aware of or that I haven't learnt in class (module ended last term) that will always hold the correct result?

If yes, why the formula above yields the incorrect result?

Comment: Didn't you want to calculate the remainder of $3^{23}$ instead of $23^{23}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks a lot for pointing this out. It seems that my module slides are incorrect.

Comment: You want powers of $724$ in the decryption stage. And use the binary expansion of $d= 47$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thanks a lot, I have understand it now from the answers given. In fact, I gave the wrong answer in the coursework that I did back then and I got full marks somehow. This also threw my reasoning into disarray.

Very much thankful for all the answers in here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thanks for editing my post, I will use your edits for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When squaring, why are you taking powers of $23$?  You want powers of $3$.
$$3^{23} = 3^{16} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 3^{1}  \text{.}  $$

\begin{align*}
3^1 &\cong 3 \pmod{1147}  \\
3^2 &\cong 9 \pmod{1147}  \\
3^4 &\cong 81 \pmod{1147}  \\
3^8 &\cong 826 \pmod{1147}  \\
3^{16} &\cong 958 \pmod{1147}  \text{ and }  \\
3^{23} &\cong 958 \cdot 81 \cdot 9 \cdot 3 \cong 724 \pmod{1147}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, like I answered to @JyrkiLahtonen, it seems that my module slides had a mistake.

I will accept this as the answer.